# Проблемы импорту aspose-words

Tags: python

Пробую освоить библиотеку aspose-words для работы с докуметнами word. Установил pip install pytest-shutil
пробую импортировать - ошибка. Код:

```
import aspose.words as aw
doc = aw.Document()
builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)
builder.writeln("Hello World!")
doc.save("Output.pdf")
```

ошибка:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 223.8836.43)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aspose'
```

Сама библиотека загружена, командой pip show aspose-words проверил. В папке на диске файли есть.
Где еще искать проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам.
Создал окружение, из которого небило доступа к гробальному Python. Я пересоздал и галочкой о наследование глобальних переменних и все заработало.